# How to migrate to Dependency Injection using repository pattern using very minimal Entity Framework

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, repository-pattern

I am trying to migrate to dependency injection using the repository pattern. I am trying to set up my repository pattern by inject the `DbCcontext` and implementing the method in my interface. My goal is to Get All Work Orders. I have a model called `WorkOrder` in my `DbContext`.

Can anyone tell me how I am to implement the method from my interface with code to get all of the work orders?

```
public class WorkOrderContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<WorkOrder> WorkOrder { get; set; }
}

public class WorkOrder
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string LocationId { get; set; }
    public string Reason { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; } = true;
    public DateTime Date { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public string StateId { get; set; } 
}
```

WorkOrderRepository

```
public class WorkOrderRepository : IWorkOrderRepository
{
    //Bringing in Db Context that will be used in Repos; 
    private WorkOrderContext _workOrderContext; 

    //Constructor that will inject the Context;
    public WorkOrderRepository(WorkOrderContext workOrderContext)
    {
        _workOrderContext = workOrderContext; 
    }

    //Implementing method from Interface; 
    public List<WorkOrder> GetWorkOrders()
    {
        return _workOrderContext.WorkOrder;            
    }
}
```

Here is my interface:

```
public interface IWorkOrderRepository
{
    List<WorkOrder> GetWorkOrders(); 
}
```

I am getting an error right here on the

```
return _workOrderContext.WorkOrder;
```

It says

> Can't convert type Entity Framework to systems collection generic

Comment: Just call the linq extension `return _workOrderContext.WorkOrder.ToList()`

Comment: That said. You will encounter those telling you that EF DbContext/DbSet is already an implementation of the repository pattern.

Comment: @Nkosi thank you. If you don't mind could you explain what its doing. Thanks.

Comment: @Nkosi thank you for the additional info. what does: "That said. You will encounter those telling you that EF DbContext/DbSet is already an implementation of the repository pattern. – Nkosi 21 secs ago" mean? Also will this method be able to get all of the records in the WorkOrder Model. Thanks again

Comment: The `.ToList<T>()` extension method basically enumerates the dbset and creates a list from the enumerated items.

Answer (score 2):

Your problematic line

```
return _workOrderContext.WorkOrder;
```

is attempting to return your repository, not the collection of results within that repo.

Instead, return the repo materialized as a list:

```
return _workOrderContext.WorkOrder.ToList();
```